# How to put a clickable URL in firestore database data, inside the "description" field

Tags: android, database, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter application and I am using firestore database, but when I add a URL in the description field and run my application, this URL is not clickable, it stays like a text, just like the rest of the description

[image: Firebase]

[image: App]

How can I make it work the way I need it?

Comment: Did GrahamD's answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a better idea to store the url on the database as a separate attribute. You can then decide when and where to display it. If you keep it in the description text then you have to search for and extract it.